# execute script in java, read both error and output streams

Tags: java, shell

I want to be able to execute an external command from java, eg "ls", and get the output, both output and error streams, as a string, and in realtime, and in the order they were generated.

So, if the output from the command is something like:

```
blah     <- to stdout
foo      <- to stderr
bar      <- to stdout
```

Then, ideally I want the output string, and the realtime output, to look like:

```
blah
foo
bar
```

Naive methods produce either:

```
blah
bar
```

(ie no stderr output)

or:

```
blah
bar
foo
```

(ie the order is rearranged so that the stdout and stderr messages are not interlaced with each other).

Comment: Use : [Apache commons exec library](http://commons.apache.org/exec/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ProcessBuilder` and set `redirectErrorStream(true)`.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't always possible.

If you use the `ProcessBuilder` API, you can merge the `stdout` and `stderr` streams into one (using `redirectErrorStream(true)`), so you can read both outputs in a single `InputStream`. But that means you can't tell from which stream the data originally came from.

If you read `stdout` and `stderr` as two streams, you will need NIO or two Java threads. In both cases, processing one output will block the other (or rather, the other stream won't be processed timely). That will lead to swapped lines.

If the child process doesn't flush the output and you use pipes, then this gets worse because `stdout` will be sent to your process in 4KB blocks while `stderr` will usually arrive line-by-line.

There is no platform-independent workaround, I'm afraid. If you only need a solution which works on Unix, you can use Pseudo TTYs ([`man 4 pty`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=pty&sektion=4)) to simulate a shell but these are hard to set up from Java since you need to call OS functions.

One approach might be to use Perl or similar to run your command in a PTY (this causes stdout to become line buffered), read stdout and stderr from there and prefix each line with `1` for stdout and `2` for stderr.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [Apache commons exec API](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) as they are more sophisticated API to use.

See [DefaultExecutor](http://commons.apache.org/exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/DefaultExecutor.html): You can :

- set a current working directory for the subprocess
- provide a set of environment variables passed to the subprocess
- **capture the subprocess output of stdout and stderr using an ExecuteStreamHandler**
- kill long-running processes using an ExecuteWatchdog
- define a set of expected exit values
- terminate any started processes when the main process is terminating using a ProcessDestroyer

Comment: It seems really complicated to use, and not obviously documented.  Does it do anything that I can't do with a ProcessBuilder?